# How do I thin out the objects in the layer while they stay at their position?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I want to thin out all the little objects in my layer while they stay at their position.

[image: my working file example]

How exactly is that possible?

Thats my file: https://www.file-upload.net/download-12349475/bild.psd.html

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to add a white stroke (or whatever color background the object is on) to the inside of the object, using a Layer Style (if, in fact, this is what you mean by "thin out the objects").

Original:
[image]

With Stroke:
[image]

Comment: thanks, but what is if the background is transparent?

Comment: In that case, the easiest method is to do what @user287001 answered below. What you need done is best handled in Illustrator anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your object is a black bitmap that is splitted to smaller shapes by a vector mask. I assume that essentially you want to edit the vector mask so that all black parts will be reduced uniformly smaller, but otherwise they save their positions. Rescaling the whole shape in a no-go idea.

In photoshop the vector masks can be exported as ai files. Do it and open the vector mask in Illustrator. Do not be afraid of a miniscule artboard. It can be enlargened, if wanted. Then do the following:

[image]